# Bundle eats all resources while gitlab-ce running

Tags: ruby, linux, resources, bundle, gitlab

I installed `gitlab-ce` on my digitalocean droplet, it works fine but very slow, im also turned off `nginx` as it thinks that time is out on simple requests, and the problem is in bundler. `bundle` process runs forever and eats all memory. What is the reason of this? I thought bundle is needed only for setup and it is not required for running as I see other gitlab processes. Even if I kill `bundle` process manually it is started again by git user. How to fix that or is it all goes as intended?

Answer (score 5):

I also have observed this on GitLab CE -- no builds were running but after the weekend, I came back into the office and GitLab was unresponsive in the browser.  I saw 4 bundle processes eating up all of the available CPU.  I restarted (gitlab-ctl restart) and things returned to normal.  I then went to the jobs page (/admin/jobs) and no builds were running when I restarted the server.  This isn't an answer... but confirmation that there seems to be a real issue here.

Answer (score 1):

When you see `bundle`, it corresponds to the GitLab Rails/Unicorn server. If it's eating up all the CPU there may be something strange happening on your server. Do you see any particular type of request in the Nginx logs that show up very often?

There are a couple of known issues that can cause pegged CPU with GitLab. For example, if a user is building a large build trace (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27724) or sometimes when viewing a large issue or merge request (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/32347). In the logs, look for suspect requests that include `trace` or `issue` or `merge_request`.

Comment: I checked logs and find  that gitlab produces a lot of activity with no client requests. Here is log [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Zmeu213/33dda00f42b134908cccf3d5b410fe39) So `gitlab` working on virtual server where only me could access it from web. It produce such log messages pretty frequently. Gitlab was recently installed and it has no users (except me), no projects, no anything